# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

i am facing problem when i try to return the length of array in react. the error is 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'. I have put this in another child component and it work but when i tried in NavBar it just show the error.

```
import React from 'react';
import './NavBar.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCartPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

const NavBar = (props) => {
    const order = props.cart
    return (
        <div className='container-fluid'>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light  justify-content-md-between justify-content-center flex-wrap">
                <a href="/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/NZcQbJM/logo2.png" alt="Red Onion Food"/></a>

                <div>
                    <a href="/" className='nav-item' > <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCartPlus} /></a>
                    <a href="/" className='nav-item login'>Login</a>
                    <a href="/" className='nav-item'><button className="btn btn-danger btn-rounded">Sign Up</button></a>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div><h6>{order.length}</h6></div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default NavBar;
```

> I dont know what to do!!!

Comment: How do you render NavBar, you should pass a prop to navbar called `cart` that is an array.

Comment: you should provide the code of parent element of NavBar, that people could have idea how `cart` is, and how `cart` to be the props of NarBar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to short-circuit the render based on the existence of the array. You're trying to render the length of `order` before the prop is available.

Try the following:

```js
<div><h6>{order && order.length}</h6></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The undefined error is because of `order is not available that time`, so you need to check for the presence of `order` and then execute.

```
{order ? order.length : 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers pretty much sorted the problem out, i.e. you are trying to literally say `undefined.length` since the prop `order` is not defined at some stage while creating/updating the component.

But there is still a cleaner solution to it IMO - `order?.length`.

And the logic of `what-if-not` (from the answer by @arun-kumar) - could also be written as - `order?.length ?? 0` or `order?.length || 0`.

More on it -

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator
3. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v3.3.0 - CRA v3.3 supports those already.

**Update** - The de-structuring is also a cleaner way. I've used it a lot, since it allows initialising the prop in case it is not defined, but easily could be over-written by different type of value - hence I think optional chaining has an advantage over it.